# C++11 и callback-функции... Есть что-нибудь новое?

Tags: callback, c++11, c++

В старом С++ работал указатель только на обычные функции, а функции - члены класса нельзя было присваивать. В C++11 появилось что-нибудь новое для реализации callback-функций?

Comment: ну лямбды там

Comment: Недавно [обсуждалось](/questions/377854).

Comment: @sitev_ru: И да, если вы объявляете callback как (например) `std::function<...>`, то вполне [можно и функцию-член](/questions/381813/).

Answer (score 5):

Да. Был введён `std::function`, позволяющий передавать для обратного вызова не только функцию, а вообще любой функциональный объект (указатели на метод класса, лямбды, привязки (см. `std::bind`) и т. д.). Пример использования этого класса приведён ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<int(std::string)> CALLBACK;

class Foo
{
private:
    int x = 13;

public:
    int callback(std::string str)
    {
        std::cout << "callback: " << str << " " << x << std::endl;
        return 17;
    }
};

class A
{
private:
    CALLBACK m_callback;

public:
    void set_callback(CALLBACK callback)
    {
        m_callback = callback;
    }

    void call_callback()
    {
        // проверка на жизнеспособность callback-a

        m_callback("privet");
    }
};



int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    Foo* ptr = new Foo();
    A* a = new A();

    a->set_callback(std::bind(&Foo::callback, ptr, std::placeholders::_1));
    //delete ptr; // контроля за жизню объекта нету
    a->call_callback();
}
```